# Xamarin ListView row is very small

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created this ContentPage with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MyApp.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMain" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="{Binding EmployeeName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteUp.png" VerticalOptions="End" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="VoteDown.png" VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageLocation}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
                            <Image Source="Favorite.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                            <Image Source="Send.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                            <Image Source="Save.png" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

But my result is as following:
[image]

However, the result I want to see should look like this:
[image]

So just to be clear:

- The width of the picture must be 85% of the screen width
- The height of the picture must be as large as the picture width, so
  that it will be a square
- The side next to the picture must be the remaining 15% of the screen
- The upper and lower part of the row must be the height of the 15% screen width

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: specify a RowHeight

Comment: Can I use percentages?

Comment: No, but you can calculate it at runtime.  There are a lot of complexities that go into calculating the layout for a ListView.  If you have a complex layout I'd suggest you try CollectionView instead

Comment: Okay, but how can I set foreach row the height? How can I access them, because I now gave them names like: `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" x:Name="Row0_Height" />`, But how can I change those then?

Comment: RowHeight is a property of the ListView

Comment: You want the single cell of listview to fill the screen?

Comment: Almost fill the screen! Something like Instagram

Comment: I would suggest you start with `HasUnevenRows` to true, Once you do that you can simply get the height of the screen and set the RowHeight Dynamically! Use FFImageLoading so you can cache this up. Make sure you handle the images correctly so you do not go OOM. Good Luck

Comment: But should I use a ListView or a CollectionView? Now you are talking about ListView again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try setting HasUnevenRows property to "True", and binding a list model to the list view, not directly in the Datatemplate